# Drupal 9 swagger-ui-formatter.js=1.0 is returning HTTP and not HTTPS

Tags: drupal, apigee

I am struggling on an issue. My drupal site using Apigee Kickstart is all https. The swagger module specifically swagger-ui-formatter.js=1.0 is returning http and giving me a mixed content error. I have spent a long time troubleshooting this issue. I can easily add a hack to the .js file but it gets overwritten each time I have an update to the module. I am trying to find out where the http is being applied. I do not think it is a database thing.

Any direction would be much appreciated.

Adding a hack to the code which gets overwritten